# journalctl output disable colorization

Tags: colors, journalctl

I have a dark background for my console so there's quite a bit of journalctl output that is unreadable.

I see lots of information about how to add color! But how do I completely disable it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can disable colour in journalctl like so;

```
SYSTEMD_COLORS=false journalctl
```

you could then add it to your ~/.bashrc, exporting the env variable;

```
export SYSTEMD_COLORS=false
```

That will be global though and may effect other systemd related things.

I guess a more direct solution would be to add an alias to your ~/.bashrc, like so;

```
alias journalctl='SYSTEMD_COLORS=false journalctl'
```